bash concatenate variables and strings
I have a config file that contains filenames without an extensions:
aa
bb

In a bash script, I read them to an array and use the filenames to build a full path:
configFile="C:/xxxx/load.config"

myarray=()

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    myarray+=("$line")
    echo "$line"
done < "$configFile"


folder="C:/project/test/"

for((i = 0; i < ${#myarray[@]}; ++i))
do
    file=${myarray[$i]}

    echo "folder="$folder
    echo "file="$file
    
    file_path=$folder$file".xml"

    echo "$file_path"
    echo "next..."

done

Here is the result that I get:
aa
bb
folder=C:/project/test/
file=aa
.xmlroject/test/aa
next...
folder=C:/project/test/
file=bb
C:/project/test/bb.xml
next...

The .xmlroject/test/aa is unexpected. Why does it output that?

Your file has CRLF line breaks. Fix it with dos2unix.

BTW, your while loop that reads the file can be replaced with the readarray command.

And your for loop can be simplified to for file in "${myarray[@]}"

You could produce the output you want from your config file with just sed 's@.*@C:/project/test/&.xml@' 'C:/xxxx/load.config', no need for multiple loops, arrays etc.

Hint: If you get weird output, have a look what is actually stored in your variable. To peek into a variable, do i.e. xxd <<<$folder.
